# VS2022 Database Project Reference Keep Breaking

Tags: visual-studio-2022, database-project

Vs2022, I have a database project. Within that project are some views and functions which refer to a system database. So I have added those system database references, both Master and MSDB to the project. The references work, all is good.

I close the solution and reopen it, and now the project shows two references to each database, and a bunch of script errors because an unresolved reference exists:

[image]

So the fix is again to remove these 4 references, add the database reference back to master and msdb, and then all is good, until I reopen the solution again!

[image]

One side note, this solution was originally created in VS2019. Also, this happens on 2 separate machines. I'm running VS 17.3.3 64-bit.

Comment: Weird, Did you try rebuilding the solution or clean and build solution??

Comment: Yep, no difference. Also note, this happens on two difference machines. Possible vs2022 bug?

Comment: Unsure if this kind of issue has been reported earlier

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem, VS 2022 adds two references to the DBs, one from VS extensions folder and the other one from SQL Server folder, its definitely a bug and happens often when updating VS 2022.

However, the solution is to delete the second one from the project references (SQL Folder Reference) and then you need to click on the project and explicitly save it by using Ctrl+S, otherwise, the change will not be saved and whenever you close and open the solution, the project will show invalid references.